# How do I move jest tests to a /test folder and get them to run?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, jestjs

**edit**: I'm pretty sure this question is out of date and Jest has changed since then. Don't assume the answers will work or even be relevant now.

Jest expects tests to be in _*tests*_ folder or to be named blah.test.js. I don't like either of those patterns. I want my test files to be in `/test` and naming them `test/index.ios.test.js` seems redundant and silly. My first stab at this is to change my jest config in package.json to be:

```
"jest": {
    "testPathDirs": ["test"],
    "testRegex": "\\.(js|jsx)$",
    "preset": "react-native"
}
```

Which find the tests successfully but they all fail:

```
Cannot find module 'setupDevtools' from 'setup.js'
  
  at Resolver.resolveModule (node_modules/jest-resolve/build/index.js:151:17)
  at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/react-native/jest/setup.js:23:1)
```

That function is in `node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Core/Devtools/setupDevtools.js`. How do I tell Jest where to find it?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I solved the problem by just setting the regex so it finds all `.js` files in my `./test` folder:

```
"jest": {
   "preset": "react-native",
    "globals": {
        "__DEV__": true
    },
    "testRegex": "./test/.*.js$",
    "rootDir": "."
 },
```

(jcollum here: I don't know what `__DEV__` is actually doing there but an error will be thrown if isn't. jest 17.0.3)

Comment: Doesn't that pattern mandate having `.test.js`? It doesn't work if I rename my test/index.ios.test.js to test/index.ios.js.

Comment: Ah sorry I misunderstood your question. Do you mean `"./test/.*\\.ios\\.js$",`

Comment: edited your answer to be the answer that I ended up figuring out. Hard to post code like that legibly in a comment

Answer (score 18):

I think the best way to go about this is to configure [testMatch](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration.html#testmatch-array-string). It defaults to:

```
[ "**/__tests__/**/*.[jt]s?(x)", "**/?(*.)+(spec|test).[jt]s?(x)" ]
```

So you could either change `__tests__` to `tests` or add a new entry into the array that checks for both. My use the following in my package.json:

```
  "jest": {
    "testMatch": [ "**/tests/**/*.[jt]s?(x)", "**/?(*.)+(spec|test).[jt]s?(x)" ]
  },
```

Comment: This is better because it preserves default behavior.

Comment: This is the [updated link](https://jestjs.io/docs/configuration#testmatch-arraystring)

Answer (score 7):

I think to set `roots: ['<rootDir>/test/']` is simple way in `jest.config.js`

```
module.exports = {
 roots: ['<rootDir>/test_unit/'],
 ...
}
```

It works well for me.